# SCCM 2007 SP2 - Could not connect or execute sql query

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2, sccm-2007

I've run into SQL database connection issues while trying to install SCCM 2007 SP2.

I have a VM setup that hosts SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 installed using default settings and setting the services to run using a new domain account named 'SCCMAdmin'. During the install I've told the SQL installer to make the SCCMAdmin a sysadmin.

During the SCCM install I get stopped by the following error.

[image: SCCM Error]

I've confirmed local and remote access using a ODBC connector and remote SQL editors with successful logins.

[image: ODBC Successful Test]

I've been over at least a hundred sites complaining about SQL database access and some getting resolved by adding the system account to the SQL server as an admin and other solutions but none have worked.

My SPN is setup properly.
[image: SPN]

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

SCCMAdmin credentials:
[image: SCCM Credentials]

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many hours of fighting I gave up and wiped the server. A clean install is what was needed as the setup completed without issue this time.

So much wasted time but I have a working SCCM environment now.

Comment: I later found out it was a botched SQL server install. Something went wrong during the install as I ran into it again later on and found that reinstalling the SQL server resolved the issue. However this is not a great solution if your environment is already in use.